# Modx phpthumbof

Tags: php, modx

Не могу разобраться почему в modx phpthumbof не работает обрезка изображений. В документации есть пример:

```
[[+imageUrl:phpthumb=`w=234&h=123&zc=1`]]
```

Вывожу точно так же у себя в чанке, в теге img, в атрибуте src, пишу следующее:

```
src="[[+image:phpthumb=`w=104&h=123&zc=1`]]"
```

В итоге выводится картинка без изменений.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я когда-то намучился с phpThumbOf нашёл переписанный (fork) вариант, в котором всё работает. Так что рекомендую. http://modx.com/extras/package/pthumb
Вот рабочий кусок с одного из проектов

```
<img src="
[[!pThumb? 
    &input=`[[*pageImage]]`
    &options=`&w=300&h=300&f=png&fltr[]=wmi|/assets/images/templates/wmismall.png/|155x270`
]]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

phpThumb поставляется вместе с modx, но для его использования как модификатора вывода, необходим сниппет который не идет в поставке. Взять его можно тут: [сниппет phpthumb для фильтра вывода](https://github.com/jaredloman/PHPThumb-Output-Filter/blob/master/phpthumb.snippet.php)

Answer (score 1):

Забудьте про phpthumbof, используйте сниппет phpthumbon (работает в разы шустрее). Использует все те же модификаторы, и вызывается так же, вот пример:

```
[[*image:phpthumbon=`w=200&h=200&zc=1`]]
```